# Can't get forms to render in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm working on a project and I don't get the django forms to render on any of my pages. I've compared it to django girls code, as that is what I usually consult but it looks virtually identical to it. It's not just this page, my other pages have issues with rendering the forms as well. Here's the code:

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
from .forms import *
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from .cart import Cart
from django.db import transaction
from django.contrib import messages


@login_required
def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=Post)
    return render(request, 'rentadevapp/post_edit.html', {'rentadevapp': post_edit}, {'form': form})
```

Forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'text',)
```

post_edit.html

```
{% extends 'rentadevapp/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/post_edit.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"><br>
        <h2>New Post</h2><br>
        <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default='0')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)

    def created(self):
        self.created_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def updated(self):
        self.updated_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I'm pretty stuck and have spent a couple hours trying to figure this out. Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you need `instance=Post` in your `else:` branch in your view function. `form = PostForm()` should suffice. Does that change anything? If not, are you getting any errors?

Comment: What version of Django?

Comment: @Chris , That did not change anything. There are no errors, nothing renders and only the other text is on the page. No form.

Comment: @markwalker_ , 2.0.5

Comment: @JamesFranco, if you inspect your page source and use your browser's dev tools do you see anything there at all?

Comment: And does `rentadevapp/base.html` (or any of its ancestor templates) also use `form`?

Comment: @Chris , I get: ```<form method="POST" class="post-form"><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='nVb6YbVOuZV7HINK96zpqgKvhm6vrx1HUn55UxURUeSU7Y7pFgISA9nSUOF0P8uc' />``` and base does not import form, or use any forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form isn't returned to the template in the context.

In Django [1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) or [2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) the `render` function call in your view should return a dictionary of context variables as the third argument, but you've got two dictionaries. The 4th argument where you've got a dictionary containing the form is being passed as `content_type` which is then used in the `HttpResponse` so I'm quite surprised there isn't something strange happening or an error seen.

So you're doing;

```
return render(request, 'rentadevapp/post_edit.html', {'rentadevapp': post_edit}, {'form': form})
```

What you need to do is;

```
context = {'form': form, 'rentadevapp': post_edit}

return render(request, 'rentadevapp/post_edit.html', context)
```

Prior to 1.10 [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/shortcuts/#render) had a different signature, but the first three arguments of `request, template_name, context` have been that way since <1.8

Comment: I don't think applies to my version of Django, 2.0.5

Comment: @JamesFranco `render` hasn't changed in a long time; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/shortcuts/#render It's been this way since 1.10

Comment: If I do that, form becomes and unresolved reference in context